# Any Netbeans plugin to save code checkpoints in order to casually play around with the code?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

Isn't there any netbeans plugin to save code checkpoints, so that I could then play around with my code, making experimental modifications to my project ?

Comment: Did you even heard of git?

Comment: I do use subversion, but I dont have the habit of committing too frequently. I do it after I make substantial amount of finalized changes to the project. May be I need to inculcate habit of frequent commits.. i was looking around for more casual approach to this:)